# Estimating the value of a stock

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, finance

I need a way to know the value of my stock. Let $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ be the quantity of the products $1$ to $n$ I have in stock, such that, for example, if I have $8$ units of the product $2$, $x_2 = 8$.

Let $j_{i,k}$ be the $k$ prices at which the product $i$ can possibly be bought.
Let $m_i$ be a movement of the stock quantity of product $i$. It's worth mentionning that $m_i$ can be both positive and negative.

The question is : how can I know the value $v_i$ of the stock of each product $i$ in order to be able to eventually know the total value of the stock $V$ given the fact that I don't know at which price the $x_i$s were bought.

The big constraint here is that there is no way to track the products individually : once they are bought, they are put with the rest of the stock thus loosing the cost information.

Do you have any idea on how to approach that ? I don't even know how to tag this question.

Thank you

Comment: I think it's not very clear what you're asking.. You say that each product can be bought at different prices and you want a general "value information". Well then either you use an "average cost " for each product or you try to estimate the actual value (ie for how much you think they'll sell). It really depends on what you have to do.. Then again I may have misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes I agree, but this is actually the point of the question how can I manage that ? Because how would you compute the average cost ? If you have 20 products, you might say that you are going to compute the average by assuming that  5 units where bought at the price p1, and 15 at p2, but you might also assume that one was bought at p1, 7 at p2, 8 at p3, and 4 for p4, or your might choose any other arrangement.
 
My question is actually that, how to compute the average cost (I'm not interested in the selling price). How do I choose the coefficients to compute the average.

Comment: If you only know how many products you have and a range of possible prices without any other information, then it's not possible to find an average cost. You can say that the average cost has to be in some interval (between the lowest and highest price) but that's it. An interesting approach would be to do educated guesses using some statistical tools but it's quite complex. Anyhow on this regard you may wait for someone else or ask on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ant I'll wait here in hope someone comes then I'll do that.

Comment: If you can think of any extra information that would make the educated guesses more easy to do , this would do the trick too. I can't track the products invidually, but I'm able to store other information if they can help.

Comment: I just said that because I read the "German tank problem " on wiki (search that, it's an awesome read) and maybe something can be said